# Panache Equivalent to Hibernate Merge?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, quarkus, entities, quarkus-panache

I'm looking to essentially do a Hibernate `merge()` or `saveOrUpdate()`.

I'm new to Hibernate and Panache but my understanding is that Hibernate's merge works in situations where I wish to insert new entities (those that don't have an ID) or update existing entities (those that do have an ID) in my underlying database. This sounds very convenient and good for reducing boilerplate code!

I've seen examples [like the one here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkusio.github.io/issues/489) which calls for using the underlying entity manager (in this case Hibernate) to do the merge, however `getEntityManager()` does not appear to be available in Panache any longer. Am I looking in the wrong place?

How can I do a Hibernate `merge()` using Panache? (I'm following the repository pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Reactive is not part of the JPA specification and therefore doesn't have an EntityManager. You can still access the session and merge entities using `Panache.getSession()`:

```
Panache.getSession()
    .chain( session -> session.merge( ... ) )
    .chain( entity ->  ... )
```

In Panache with JPA, `Panache.getEntityManager()` [is still available](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/panache/hibernate-orm-panache/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/hibernate/orm/panache/Panache.java#L24) and you should be able to do:

```
Panache.getEntityManager().merge(...);
```

or

```
MyEntity.getEntityManager().merge(...);
```

Panache doesn't have a direct method so you have to use the one in the `EntityManager` or `Session`.

> This sounds very convenient and good for reducing boilerplate code!

Kinda, but it's not as efficient as persisting a new entity or saving changes if you know which operation you want to do in advance.

Comment: I went ahead and accepted your answer because I switched to hibernate-orm-panache and found that you are correct! However in [hibernate-reactive-panache](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/panache/hibernate-reactive-panache/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/hibernate/reactive/panache/Panache.java) I just found that getEntityManager() doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm okay with the performance tradeoff. This will be for a singular row and my understanding is that under the hood hibernate is just checking to see if an id is provided. No id do insert, provided id do update. Over thousands of rows that might be problematic but for small batches I'm okay with that loss. :D

Comment: You didn’t specify which one . In reactive there is ‘Panache.getSession()’

Comment: I've updated the answer to include Hibernate Reacive